# Setting @Table in run time Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am writing a spring service to connect to my PostgreSQL SQL server using JPA . The problem that I am facing is how to set @Table to a value at run time . I am having two tables , one for QA and other for prod . So when I execute the jar , I am setting the profile to QA or prod , but I am not able to get how to set @Table to corresponding table for the given profile .

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=.\vmconfig -Dspring.profiles.active=qa postgre-1.0.1.jar

Properties File

server.port= 6869   
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx-xxx/DB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

@Table(name=<>) --> The name should be set at runtime based on the profile in which jar is executed.

Comment: Which is why the JPA spec defines `orm.xml` ...

Answer (score 1):

**You have three options:**

### **orm.xml** (Recommended)

You can define an orm.xml. With it, you can override the entity's table name.
Normally you would have dropped the orm.xml in your resources/META-INF folder. But this will then apply for all your profiles, as Spring Boot will load it automatically.

For your case, you want it only for a specified profile. For this, you need to create the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. (Instead of just setting the properties) ([Example here](https://github.com/pfac/demo-spring-data-jpa-hibernate-h2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/iampfac/demo/config/ApplicationConfiguration.java))

On `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` you can then set location for orm.xml.

For example:

```
@Bean
@Profile("QA")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    bean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.demo");
    bean.setMappingResources("orm.xml");
    return bean;
}
```

This configuration should only then be applied to the required profile.

Here is a simple example of an orm.xml

```
<entity-mappings version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">

<entity class="com.example.demo.EntityName">
    <table name="NEW_TABLE_NAME"></table>
</entity>
```

*Thanks @BillFrost for pointing this out.

### @EntityScan per environment

You can supply different `@EntityScan` per environment configuration. Thus scan for only QA entities in the QAConfiguration. This requires you to create duplicate Entities with different names defined in the @Table.

I really do not like this, as it causes you to have to maintain a QA set of entities and a production set. *This is just a production issue waiting to happen.*

### Overriding SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy

Lastly, you can extend the SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy, you can then modify that specific table name. This bean then should only be active in the QA profile.

```
@Bean
public SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy springPhysicalNamingStrategy() {
    return new SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy() {
        @Override
        public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
            // Just change find and replace your table name
            return super.toPhysicalTableName(new Identifier( name.getText(), false), jdbcEnvironment);
        }
    };
}
```

**ALSO: Just check how to construct an `Identifier` to your DB's naming requiements.