# Spring, H2 define different annotation value for different Environments

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, h2

a quick overview of the situation.
I have a Postgres database with a field "JSONB" and I have connected it to my Spring application, in which I use Hibernate as ORM. I've defined my custom JSON type and assigned that type to the respective Postgres column:

```
@Column(name = "note", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
@Type(type = "JsonNoteType")
private JsonNote jsonNote;
```

Everything here works fine, the problem araises because I also want to have a second Test environment, in which I load the data into an H2 in memory database.
Since H2 does not support JSONB type, I have to tell him to treat it as a "other" object, this results in having the **columnDefinition** changed:

```
@Column(name = "note", columnDefinition = "other")
@Type(type = "JsonNoteType")
private JsonNote jsonNote;
```

For now I have been changing manually that field depending on the tests that I wanted to run.

How could I configure my application to change the value of the annotation columnDefinition?

I cannot load the value from application.properties because of the "time" at which variables are evaluated, so I was thinking more about a Run Configuration setting, but still don't know how. Any suggestion would be helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide an ORM.xml.
Within the ORM.xml you can override the column definition. And also you can set the ORM.xml location per environment. (You will need to manually configure it)

Unfortunately, you will need a bit of setup to do this, but have a look at 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495289/setting-table-in-run-time-spring/50496790#50496790) It can help.

Comment: This might actually be a good solution, the only problem I see is that when rebuilding the entire project importing Maven's dependencies this fix would break, maybe I could just write a patch file to rewrite the orm.xml after import, but I still hope for a cleaner solution ^^

Comment: You can have the same build for every environment, and specify what Spring Profile should be active when running the application (-D parameter), (Thus setting the active application-PROFILE.properties file).